# bluetooth headset to phone

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, headset

I want to forward all sound from a bluetooth headset's microphone to the phone's stereo -- so the sound that you will hear from your phone will be the same as the input of the bluetooth headset's microphone.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please note that app-recommendations are off topic here (see our [FAQ]: *Can you suggest an app that does X?*). I re-phrased your question to reflect your real problem, and avoid it from being closed as off topic.

Comment: Ok, but how do i get people to answer, i posted this an hour ago...

Comment: Simply wait -- one hour is not that long. You cannot *expect* immediate answers (though often they do come). Give it a little time, until someone found an answer. Not everybody here is all-knowing -- so it needs the right person finding and answering it.

Comment: Anyone going to answer?

Comment: If somebody knows an answer, it might come. Pushing is not helpful. Sorry if it looks disappointing -- I would have answered if I knew an answer, and I'm pretty sure this applies to others as well. Maybe, as your question's last sentence already assumes, it's not possible (or no solution does currently exist) -- in which case nobody can have an answer?